# How to get the XML file (which is stored in SQL DB) size?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

In my DB the data is stored in binary format, and with the SQL query I'm converting it to XML by using CAST in my query.

Now, I would like to get the XML file within SQL by adding another column.

**Note**: I don't want to export those data in file location as it has huge records.

Query used:

```
select 
  AR.Column1, 
  AR.Column2, 
  CAST (Message as XML) AS "XML FILE"
from 
  [dbo].[Table1] AP 
  INNER JOIN [DBName].[dbo].[Table2] AR ON AR.Column1=AP.Column1 
where 
  (AR.InsertedDate BETWEEN '2019-11-19 00:00:00.000' AND '2019-11-19 23:59:59.477') 
  and AR.Column2='Delta' order by InsertedDate desc
```

Comment: It's still not clear to me from your question what you're after, but the size of an XML or binary column (in bytes) can be determined with `DATALENGTH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATALENGTH` becomes really helpful when used with data types that can store variable-length data, such as:

> image
>   ntext
>   nvarchar
>   text
>   varbinary
>   varchar

```
SELECT AR.Column1, AR.Column2, 
       CAST (Message as XML) AS "XML FILE",
       CASE WHEN DATALENGTH(Message) <= 1024 THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DATALENGTH(Message)) + ' BYTES'
            WHEN DATALENGTH(Message) >1024 AND DATALENGTH(Message) <= 1048576 THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DATALENGTH(Message)/1024) + ' KB'
            WHEN DATALENGTH(Message) >1048576 AND DATALENGTH(Message) <= 1073741824 THEN   CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DATALENGTH(Message)/1048576) + ' MB'
            WHEN DATALENGTH(Message) >1073741824 AND DATALENGTH(Message) <= 109951162777  THEN   CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DATALENGTH(Message)/1073741824) + ' GB'
            ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DATALENGTH(Message)/109951162777) + ' TB' END AS "XML FILE SIZE"
FROM  [dbo].[Table1] AP 
INNER JOIN [DBName].[dbo].[Table2] AR ON AR.Column1=AP.Column1 
WHERE  (AR.InsertedDate BETWEEN '2019-11-19 00:00:00.000' AND '2019-11-19 23:59:59.477') 
       AND AR.Column2='Delta' 
ORDER BY InsertedDate DESC
```

Comment: Yes you can get it since file size is integer value

Comment: @ManiRaghavendra Can you please post the new question with expected data and sample input?